# error encoding string as unicode in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, unicode

I want to print the unicode version of a string in Python 2.7. It works fine in Python 3.
But with python 2.7, I get the following error:

```
x="strings are now utf-8 \u03BCnico\u0394é!"
```

**Python 3:**

```
print('Python', python_version())
print(x)

Python 3.4.1
strings are now utf-8 μnicoΔé!
```

**Python 2.7**

```
>>> x='strings are now utf-8 \u03BCnico\u0394é!'
>>> x.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 38: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**EDIT:**
I tried the followimg:

```
>>> x = u'strings are now utf-8 \\u03BCnico\\u0394\xc3\xa9!'
>>> x
u'strings are now utf-8 \\u03BCnico\\u0394\xc3\xa9!'
>>> x.encode("utf-8")
'strings are now utf-8 \\u03BCnico\\u0394\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9!'
>>> x
u'strings are now utf-8 \\u03BCnico\\u0394\xc3\xa9!'
```

I don't see the encoding happening

EDIT 2:

```
>>> x=u'strings are now utf-8 \u03BCnico\u0394é!'
>>> x.encode("utf-8")
'strings are now utf-8 \xce\xbcnico\xce\x94\xc3\xa9!'
>>> b=x.encode("utf-8")
>>> b
'strings are now utf-8 \xce\xbcnico\xce\x94\xc3\xa9!'
>>>
```

Comment: Your first problem is that you're trying to encode a byte string. You **decode byte strings** into unicode, and you **encode unicode** into byte strings in a particular encoding (`utf-8` for example).

Comment: Just try printing the unicode literal ```print x``` without the ```.encode()```.

Comment: Your second problem is that you're trying to use unicode escape sequences (`\u...`) in a byte string - they only work in unicode literals, as demonstrated in @LyndsySimon's answer.

Comment: In your edited part, you use unicode literals, but somehow managed to escape the unicode escape sequences *twice* (`\\u`), which will prevent them from working as intended. Just use the string from your very first line, but as an unicode literal (`u'strings...'`), and encode *that* to `utf-8`, if you so desire.

Comment: Also: `str.encode()` doesn't operate in place like you seem to assume in your edited part. You'll need to look at the result of `encode()` to see the encoding taking place, the original string won't change.

Comment: @LukasGraf: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried what you suggested. but still it is not printing the unicode literals. please see EDIT 2 above.

Comment: @eagertoLearn because you're not `print`ing it - print that last string, and you'll see. What Python shows you if you just enter a variable in the interpreter is the *representation* of a string.

Comment: Since you're @eagertoLearn, I strongly suggest to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) ;-) There's quite a bit of history involved in how this mess we're in came to be, and knowing it will help you remember how it all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2.x, you'll need to use the [unicode literal:](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code)

```
x=u"strings are now utf-8 \u03BCnico\u0394é!"
```

Without this, the `encode` method doesn't know what encoding the string is, and assumes that it is ASCII. It then tries to convert ASCII to UTF-8, and fails when it encounters a character outside the ASCII character set.

Note also that Python 3.3 and above supports this notation. It's basically a no-op in that context because all strings are assumed unicode, but allows developers to write code that is compatible with both 2.x and 3.3+.

Comment: I reviewed the comments on your OP - do you still need me to review your changes?